# Fail compile Sass with gulp

Tags: javascript, sass, compilation, gulp

I have a problem with my code. it will not compile when I write "Gulp sass" in the console, But nothing happened in my CSS folder. I have been sitting for a long time trying to make it work but it won't want to work for me and I am very grateful if anyone can help me with this

Here is the code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');


// Compile
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/Assests/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/Assets/css'));
});`
```

and in the console it says

```
gulp sass
[10:41:41] Using gulpfile ~\my-app\gulpfile.js
[10:41:41] Starting 'sass'...
[10:41:41] Finished 'sass' after 8.78 ms`
```

Comment: Are you sure `'./src/Assests/scss/*.scss'` is correct? Looks like a typo to me.

Comment: i think its right look the gif there i hope i did it right https://gyazo.com/a271a58b6423d2c446757efefb250219

Comment: you right it is typo thanks for helping I didn`t see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure the name of the folder is correct.  Looks like you have 'Assests' instead of 'Assets'.  Note the extra 's'

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to log errors `sass().on('error', sass.logError)`

You task:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {

    return gulp.src('./src/Assests/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass()
           .on('error', sass.logError)  
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/Assets/css'));
});
```

Comment: While this should be a comment and not an answer, cause this could reveal the cause, but not solve it, I’m going to give you +1

Comment: Thanks for the help but it was typo thing. Really thanks for the help!